# Full-screen UICollectionViewCell issue on iPhone X in landscape

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios11, iphone-x

In my app, I present a view controller modally, and this view controller contains a `UICollectionView` that fills the superview. Each cell in the collection view needs to be full-screen - the same size as the view's bounds. To accomplish this, I simply set the `itemSize` of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to be the view's bound's size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

This works really well on all devices and orientations, except iPhone X in landscape. When presenting that screen in that case, it seems the safe area layout margins are coming into play and affecting positioning of the cell. The cell is pushed over from the left edge of the display, and pushed up such that the bottom of the cell is aligned to the vertical center of the home indicator. Inspecting the layout with View Debugger reveals the collection view fills the screen, but the cell's Y position is -10.67 and the X position is 0, even though it is inset from the leading of the collection view. Notably, this is logged in the console:

```
The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fa6311253b0>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fa63207e800; frame = (0 0; 812 375); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x608000244d70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60800023ef00>; contentOffset: {-44, 0}; contentSize: {0, 812}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 44, 21, 44}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fa6311253b0>.
```

What's going on here and how can this be resolved?

Comment: Just curious, why not set the itemSize inside of `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` instead of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: Also, if setting itemSize with the first mentioned, make sure to use `view.frame` for width and height as opposed to `view.bounds`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, iOS 11 automatically adjusts content insets for iPhone X in landscape, causing this issue to occur. To resolve it, you can simply disable the automatic content inset adjustment, as it's not needed nor desired in this scenario.

`collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Comment: Worked perfectly! I was trying to use `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutSectionInsetReference` to turn this off but that seemed to be doing something other than this.

Comment: Hi, I've added this behavior to my collection in the didSet observer and I'm setting the cell size at `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` like `return self.view.frame.size` but I'm still having problems in landscape only for the iPhone X. Is there something else I should check?